# CASE returns Chinese characters when asked to return a VARBINARY column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, key-value

I am trying to retrieve values from a key/value table using the following query. In case the value of the *key* column is "OrderNumber" or "CustomerNumber", then, instead of the *val* column, I would like to have another column's value (*valHash*) from the same key/value table (we can almost call it a *key/value/hashvalue* table).

But when I run the query I get Chinese characters when my CASE meets its first condition:

```
SELECT IssueId, 
    customfield,
    CASE 
        WHEN customfield IN ('OrderNumber', 'CustomerNumber') THEN valHash
        ELSE val
    END AS Value,
    valHash
FROM MyTable
```

The valHash column data type is `VARBINARY`.

Comment: What datatype is `val`?

Comment: A `case` expression can only return a single datatype. The rules of [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) apply if you mix types, e.g. if `val` and `valHash` are different types.

Comment: @HoneyBadger `NVARCHAR(50)`

Comment: You can't really mix string and binary datatypes, you'll have to convert one to the other, depending on what you want to show. Or, perhaps better, show them in different columns.

Comment: @HoneyBadger In that case it's better to have everything in string.

Comment: So if `valHash`  is binary how do you want it as string - just `'0x1234'`? And why the necessity to have one column for these two different types of thing?

Comment: @MartinSmith a string version of the varbinary value maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may occur in Val. Since one column has one datatype, you could opt for this:

```
SELECT IssueId, 
    customfield,
    CASE 
        WHEN customfield IN ('OrderNumber', 'CustomerNumber') THEN valHash
        ELSE CAST (val AS VARBINARY (500))
    END AS Value,
    valHash
FROM MyTable
```

If you want everything as a string, you might want to use this:

```
SELECT IssueId, 
    customfield,
    CASE 
        WHEN customfield IN ('OrderNumber', 'CustomerNumber') THEN CONVERT (NVARCHAR (50), Valhash, 2)
        ELSE val )
    END AS Value,
    valHash
FROM MyTable
```

If you insist on differentiation between VARCHAR and VARBINARY is different cases, you need an extra column.

Comment: `CAST (valHash` as `varchar` will give them the same issue with garbage characters because the underlying binary data isn't a meaningful string. You would need `CONVERT` with a style parameter.

Comment: @SQL_M yes, I still get weird characters with `CAST (valHash AS VARCHAR (500))`

Comment: @Disasterkid - `CONVERT (NVARCHAR (50), Valhash, 2)` will give you a string representation of the hex in the `varbinary`

Comment: @Disasterkid, yeah, with some guidance from Martin.  ;)

Comment: @MartinSmith kudos to you too, sir!